# How to format Java code snippets programmatically

Tags: java

I'm looking for a java library to format/beautify Java code snippets. So for I have been using Google Java Format however it seems to work just for fully-fledged Java classes and not for code snippets. For example, the following code snippet has been formatted online without an issue:

```
@Bean public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() {
  JettyServletWebServerFactory factory = new JettyServletWebServerFactory();
  factory.setPort(9000);
  factory.setContextPath("/myapp");
  factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/notfound.html"));
  return factory;
}
```

But using Google Formatter, the following error is returned:

```
 error: class, interface, or enum expected
```

I've used the following code to attempt parsing it:

```
String formattedSource = new Formatter().formatSource(code);
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Take a look at `org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.CodeFormatter`. This plugin uses it https://github.com/revelc/formatter-maven-plugin/blob/main/src/main/java/net/revelc/code/formatter/java/JavaFormatter.java

Comment: Looks like the Google formatter only formats entire Java compilation units, not single methods. If you know it's a method, you could put a class declaration around the method before formatting. If the declaration that you put around it is properly formatted, the `formatSource` method shouldn't change it, so you can lift out the formatted method again after formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Create custom template code as a full compilation unit and remove the template back to snippet after formatting.

see below

```
    public String formatSnippet(String snippet) throws FormatterException {
    final String CUNIT = "class code { public method() { /*;*/";
    String fCode = new Formatter().formatSource(CUNIT + snippet + "/*;*/}}");
    int startIndex = fCode.indexOf("/*;*/") + 5;
    int endIndex = fCode.indexOf("/*;*/", startIndex) - 1;
    return startIndex > 0 && endIndex > 0 && endIndex > startIndex ? fCode.substring(startIndex, endIndex) : snippet;
}
```

Comment: [A user will not accept an answer if it does not explain what it does](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). In other words, this answer is code-only. Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: Thank you for complying and giving an explanation to provide a [better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)! +1.